# How can I get value of specific property of an object from the array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays

I need help in getting the values from an object, which is inside an array. For example, if I declare instance variables in `Menu` class as:

```
private String id;
private String name;
private double price;
```

and then I initialized the array as

```
Menu[] food = {new Menu("F01", "Burger", 10.00), ...};
```

How do I get the price of the food when the user inputs the id of Menu? How should I do that?

Comment: It would be much more convenient to store menus in a ‘Map<String, Menu> menusByIds’. Then you’ll be able to simply ‘menusByIds.get(inputtedId)’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
Menu[] menus = {new Menu("FO1","Burger",10.00),
        new Menu("FO2","Pizza",20.00)
    };

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your id");
String menuId = scanner.nextLine();
```

To loop through the array you can use either Java 8 Stream or normal for loop.

**Method 1: (For loop)**

```
for (int i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
        if(menus[i].getId().equals(menuId)){
            System.out.println(menus[i].getPrice());
        }
    }
```

**Method 2: (Stream)**

```
Arrays.stream(menus).filter(menu -> menu.getId().equals(menuId))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(menu -> {
                System.out.println(menu.getPrice());
            });
```